# error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'entries' with value 'array/list')

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am new in android development and developing pref.xml (resource type prefrence) using eclipe software. Here is my pref.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<EditTextPreference
 android:title="EditText"
 android:key = "name"
 android:summary="Enter Your name"
 ></EditTextPreference>

 <CheckBoxPreference
 android:title="CheckBox"
 android:defaultValue="true"
 android:key="checkBox"
 android:summary="check this box"
 ></CheckBoxPreference>

 <ListPreference
 android:title="List"
 android:key="list"
 android:summary="This Is A List To Choose From"
 android:entries="array/list"
 ></ListPreference>
```

and i got this error :

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'entries' with value 'array/list')
```

Please help me.. how do i handle this error ?

Comment: This: **android:entries="array/list"** has to be **android:entries="@array/list"**

Comment: have tried but not working...

Comment: You will also need another array attribute, called `entryValues`: **android:entryValues="@array/listValues"**. Because `entries` is what the ListPreference displays. Then in `entryValues` there are the corresponding values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find file name strings.xml in res\value folder in your package explorer...
add following line in this file

```
<string-array name="list"></string-array>
```

Your Final file look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Muzafar Khan</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

<string-array name="list"></string-array>
```

Now save your project... and enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
android:entries="array/list"
```

**to**

```
android:entries="@array/list"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to load the entries from the array resource file, correct? If so, you need to do "@array/list" instead. All of the resources (string, id, etc) must be prefixed with @ in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

`android:entries="@+array/list"`

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
android:entries="@array/list"
```

gives an error, you have to use

```
android:entries="@+array/list
```

Comment: Could you please explain why the `+` is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create resource type 'arrays' in the 'res' folder where the array elements will be defined after declaring the array type in the pref_general.xml file. 
In the arrays.xml file you can define as

```xml
       <string-array name="**array name**">
            <item>@string/**array element 1**</item>
            <item>@string/**array element 2**</item>
        </string-array>



So in your pref general file you will actually define array as
```

android:entryValues="@array/**array name**"

```
So in your string file you define the array elements as strings in normal way

Cheers
```

Answer (score 0):

go to values package create a new xml file 
for ex- `array.xml` 
then

```
<resources>
<string-array name="list"></string-array>
```

set the string-array 
and change

```
android:entries="array/list"
```

to

```
android:entries="@array/list"
```

for refering the file 
: